# WPF TreeView binding through XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

So I have a class structure like this

```
Store
    Owner
    Cashier
    List of Products
        Product Name
        Price
    List of Vendors
        Company Name
        Contact Name
```

So there are 4 objects: Store, Person (Owner and Cashier), Product and Vendor.

I want to find a way to bind this structure into a XAML tree, so each node is represents an object of this structure like:

[image http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/9337/treexq.png](http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/9337/treexq.png)

Up until now, I've only been able to this with one top object -> one sub object. Like this:

```
Store
   - Departmen 1 Products
       Book 1
       Book 2
       Book 3
   - Department 2 Products
       Bike 1
       Bike 2
       Bike 3
```

So the important difference here is that in the first tree, the sub nodes are 3 different types of object (Store has 2 Person objects, 1 Product and 1 Vendor objects); and in the second one, each root node has only one type of sub node (Store has Department, Department has Products).

I've done the second example using HierarchicalDataTemplates, so I thought this would solve my problem, but it doesn't. Any Idea on how I can do this? Here's the code that creates the Store structure:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new List<Store>() { Store.CreateStore() };
    }
}

public class Store
{
    public string StoreName { get; set; }
    public Person Owner { get; set; }
    public Person Cashier { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public List<Vendor> Vendors { get; set; }

    public Store()
    {
        this.Products = new List<Product>();
        this.Vendors = new List<Vendor>();
    }

    public static Store CreateStore()
    {
        Store store = new Store();

        // set name
        store.StoreName = "Book store";

        // set staff
        store.Owner = new Person() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith" };
        store.Cashier = new Person() { FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Smart" };

        // add products
        store.Products.Add(new Product() { Name = "Mechanical Pencil", Price = 1.25m});
        store.Products.Add(new Product() { Name = "Pen", Price = 2.50m });
        store.Products.Add(new Product() { Name = "WPF Book", Price = 28.94m });
        store.Products.Add(new Product() { Name = "ASP.NET Book", Price = 29.50m });

        // add vendors
        store.Vendors.Add(new Vendor() { CompanyName = "Bic", ContactName = "Bill Gates" });
        store.Vendors.Add(new Vendor() { CompanyName = "O'Reilly", ContactName = "Steve Jobs" });

        return store;
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

public class Vendor
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
}
```

I want to avoid creating the tree structure in the code side. Any help will be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a great post [Organizing Heterogeneous Data on a WPF TreeView](http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/12/heterogeneous-wpf-treeview) that solved this problem using MultiBinding to combine the different collections and objects together, and a MultiValueConverter to "shape" the tree of items. Solved a lot of my problems, but still working on styling it to my taste.

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok this looks like it's exactly what I need. I'll get back to you. Thanks!!

Comment: Finally had time to test this. Works like a charm, thank you!